# Yiistrap setting button type in TbNav

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

im learning how to use yiistrap and i want to set the type of buttons on the nav bar. this is my code:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavBar',array(
    'brandLabel'=>TbHtml::b(Yii::app()->name),
    'color'=>TbHtml::NAVBAR_COLOR_INVERSE,
    'display'=>null,
    'items'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

i also would like to put the navbar as fixed.. i know its set 'display=TbHtml::NAVBAR_DISPLAY_FIXEDTOP, but it takes some of the body content like.. the navbar is rendered over the header text making it hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you mean to say that the top navbar (as showcased [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/starter-template.html)) hides the first 30 some pixels of the content below.

This is a known issue in both Bootstrap and any derivate frameworks. To solve it you'd need to inject a CSS rule `body { padding-top: 60px; }` between the regular `bootstrap.css` and the `bootstrap-responsive.css` (also displayed in the example I linked above). Yiistrap doesn't do this automatically.

You could modify the extension or manually load both core and responsive CSS, though.

Extending the `TbApi` class found in `bootstrap/components/` and overriding the `registerAllCss()` method to load the fix mentioned above in-between `registerCoreCss()` and `registerResponsiveCss()` works.

Or instead of using `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register()` to get the CSS and JS injected into your views you could manually call all methods that get called by `register()` (as defined in `TbApi` class named above). This would enable you to inject the fix at the right time and place as well.

**Edit:** About changing the appearance of the navbar contents. You can use `class => '…'` as pointed out by Skullcrasher to assign specific classes to particular items in the navbar. Other than that you can add additional rules to your own stylesheet to modify how the navbar looks. Yiistrap (and Bootstrap) only provide 2 choices by default, the white and the black navbar. Anything else has to be defined by you.

Comment: thank you for your help. im not good at css though and i never thought it would be a framework problem, i fixed this problem adding a main.css into 'themeName'/css with the content body{padding-top: 60px;} and registered the css using the stylesheet function. now i just want to know how to change the buttons color and style on the navbar

Comment: Assuming any answer provided for this question solved your issue you should mark it as acceptable answer. I added some information on changing the appearance of the navbar to my initial answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

To set the button types (I assume you are talking about, success,alert,warning buttons) you can set the class of each button in the TbNav items array (each item is a button). Just add a bootstrap button class (btn-*..) for the item you want to change e.g.

```
'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index'),'class'=>'btn-error'),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page'), 'class'=>'btn-succes'),
            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
        ),
```